# How to access firebase's environment configuration form a react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I created the configurations with `firebase functions:config:set` but when I try to access them I get an error:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const config = {
    apiKey: functions.config().todoservice.apikey,
    ....
};
const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config)
export { fire }
```

That's what the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) recommends.

The `todoservice` that I am trying to access does exist.

But when I `npm run build` I get the following error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/www/firebase-app/node_modules/isemail/lib'
```

Based on research I tried using few different versions of `firebase-admin` and `firebase-functions` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you trying to use firebase-admin and firebase-functions in the javascript for a web page?  You can't do that - those are for backend components only.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes I'm trying to use them in a react app! is there any other way to do this? Trying to figure out a way to not hard code the configurations

Comment: Request them from a Cloud Function.  Or read them out of your database.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. So do I delete this question or leave it?

Comment: Given that what you initially set out to do is impossible, I'd just delete the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson I disagree, knowing that it is impossible to do is helpful for others wasting time trying to do the same. I would leave it.

Comment: @JoshPittman I did decide to leave it. I decided to remove it only if a lot of people ask for it to be removed